# nginx and apache - Error processing php files

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

I am still learning nginx, so please bear with me if the answer is obvious :).

I have set up nginx in front of apache using [these instructions](http://hybridlogic.co.uk/2011/07/setting-up-nginx-in-front-of-apache2-on-ubuntu-server/)

nginx seems to be properly processing html files, however anytime I try and access a php file I get a 404 error.

here is the nginx example.com conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/nginx.error.log;
    root /var/www/example.com/prod;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    location \ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php/$uri;
    }
    location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    return 404;
            }
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

and here is my apache example.com conf file

```
<VirtualHost 123.45.67.89:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    #Indexes + Directory Root
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/prod/

    #CGI Directory
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/example.com/prod/cgi-bin/
    <location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </location>

    #Log Files
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I've been trying to figure out where my error is for the better part of 4 hours now. I am hoping you might be able to help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;` and `<VirtualHost 123.45.67.89:8080>`
doesn't look the same.

And nginx config looks wrong. Maybe you will have better luck if you read [the official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/).

Comment: You were right, I changed the VirtualHost to <VirtualHost *:8080> and it worked...

Comment: You should change to 127.0.0.1:8080 if you want to listen only local interface which would be more secure.